# Quiet, no moving parts laptop/tablet that can run Linux?

Tags: laptop, quiet-computing, fanless

I'm looking for a laptop without any mechanical moving parts (don't need CD; will use SSD), particularly without a fan because a fan is noisy or becomes noisy after a while.

Preferably 13-15'', around 8gb ram, that can run xubuntu comfortably. Touchscreen or screen flipping are unnecessary. Could also be a tablet+ keyboard, if fast enough.

Under $800.

Are there any laptops these days like that?

Comment: Can you provide more requirements for the laptop you want? The search would be much too broad as it stands. Please see the [quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/155) for info on how to improve your question.

Comment: Many detachable tablets have driver issues running Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chromebook would be ideal for this.
I have the asus c300 chromebook and installed linux on it, works perfectly.
You can see a review of chromebooks here: http://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/laptops/best-chromebooks-top-5-chromebooks-in-the-us-1233696

It's silent, has long battery life and is cheap.

You can see how to install linux on a chromebook here: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343

Comment: Chromebook pixel is quite expensive. How can I know if this method of installing Linux would work on other Chromebooks?

Comment: It is a bit expensive, maybe not worth it if you compared the price and hardware to other laptops. 
Regarding the installation of linux, you can install it on both the ARM and Intel chipset, which are the 2 different versions in the different chromebooks.  If you want to go with linux i would suggest the intel chipset, since it can use linux to its full potential.